# C# Json.Net сериализация DynamicObject

Tags: c#, .net-core, json.net

Имеется дочерний класс от DynamicObject, при попытке сериализации с помощью JSON.NET на выходе получается пустой обьект. Что можно с этим поделать? Использовать ExpandoObject не вариант, т.к. необходим доступ к "полям" по ключу.

```
public class DataObject : DynamicObject
{
    public IDictionary<string, object> Values;

    public DataObject(IDictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        Values = values;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        if (Values.ContainsKey(binder.Name))
        {
            result = Values[binder.Name];
            return true;
        }
        result = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

P.S. Пример, как я пытаюсь сериализировать:

```
File.WriteAllText("test.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj));
```

Обьект представляет из себя сложный граф достаточно внушительных размеров

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скройте торчащее наружу поле Values и реализуйте интерфейс `IDictionary<string, object>`:

```
public class DataObject : DynamicObject, IDictionary<string, object>
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> values;

    public object this[string key] {
      get { return values[key]; }
      set { values[key] = value; }
    }

    //...
```

Свежие версии студии могут сгенерировать такую реализацию автоматически.

Объекты, реализующие `IDictionary<,>`, обрабатываются сериализатором особым образом - именно так, как вам требуется.

---

Если же вы пытаетесь использовать DynamicObject **только** для сериализации - выкиньте его, и используйте внутренний словарь непосредственно.

Comment: А можно подробнее про свежие версии студии?

Comment: @VladD те, которые основаны на Roslyn. VS2015, например.

Comment: А как заставить сгенерировать? Просто через implement interface?

Comment: @VladD [Implement interface through values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiR9x.png)